# fadeTo() fades ALL images instead of the hovered image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using the .fadeTo()  jQuery effect on the featured images on wordpress. How I have setup the code is that if the mouse hovers over the image, it fades to 0.7, when the mouse leaves, it fades back to 1:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.image').mouseover(function() {
        $('.image').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
    });
    $('.image').mouseout(function() {
        $('.image').fadeTo('fast', 1); 
    });
});
```

});

The class given is ".image" and I have put it in a div within the wordpress loop on the featured image code likes this:

```
<div class="image"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?> <!-- If has featured image, GET --></div>
```

The problem that I'm running into is that every time I'm hovering over a SINGLE image, it fades ALL images on the page. What I really want is to have it fade the image that my mouse is hovering over, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can simplify this to: `$('.image').hover( function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7); }, function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.1); });`.

Comment: Thanks! still learning the jQuery language - so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all images have the `.image` class on them, [jQuery is returning all](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) of those images when you hover over any of them.

Try changing the

```
$('.image').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
```

to

```
$(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
```

and same for the mouseout event as well.

Here's a quick [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/Fr6rY/1/) to help.

Comment: Duh! Why haven't I even bothered to try that out. Thanks for the answer, will mark after the 10 min ;)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped =) I've definitely had those moments before!

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a mouseover event on that element fired you do not need to call the jQuery selector again.

Using `$('.image')` you will call all elements with that class and apply the fade to them. If you use `this` instead then you refer only to the element that has the mouse over it. You can try this instead:

```
$('.image').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
});
$('.image').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1); 
});
```